# Signal 'show' not emitted from GUI constructed with GtkBuilder?

Tags: c, signals, gtk3, gtkbuilder

I am trying to initialize a GtkEntry widget from GSettings, through a signal handler for the 'show' signal. This works as expected when manually building the user interface, but fails to work when using GtkBuilder. The same applies to other GtkWidget signals; GtkEntry signals work as expected. It looks like the signal is never emitted?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


void activated (GtkEntry *entry,
               gpointer  user_data){

    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(user_data), GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                                               GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                               gtk_entry_get_text(entry));
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);

}



void shown (GtkWidget *widget,
               gpointer   user_data){
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(user_data), GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                                               GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                               "SHOWN!");
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);

}



int main(int argc, char **argv){
    GtkWidget *window1, *window2, *entry;
    GtkBuilder *builder;


    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Construct working window 1

    window1 = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window1),"Working");
    entry=gtk_entry_new();

    g_signal_connect(entry, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activated), window1);
    g_signal_connect(entry, "show", G_CALLBACK(shown), window1);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_WINDOW(window1), entry);


    // Construct not working window 2

    builder=gtk_builder_new_from_file ("window.glade");
    window2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window2"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
    g_object_unref(builder);


    gtk_widget_show_all(window1);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window2);


    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

window.glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window2">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Not working</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="shadow_type">none</property>
        <signal name="activate" handler="activated" object="window2" swapped="no"/>
        <signal name="show" handler="shown" object="window2" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Just a note. As far as I'm aware it is better to use **map** event for purposes for which show is intended to be used. This works the exactly way as **show**, no need to change anything in glade. And show were called as "No, not really. It's one of those weird historical things from
pre-1.0". You can check this link https://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2010/10/13/those-realize-map-widget-signals/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the visible flag in [GLADE](https://glade.gnome.org/) to false (untick) so that when GtkBuilder instantiates the glade file contents, the widget isn't shown; then when you do `gtk_widget_show_all` for `window2`, the signal will get emmited.

[image]

Alternatively, edit **`window.glade`** and set the visible property to False or remove it (I think that by default the widget isn't visible), eg:

```
 ...
 <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
    <property name="visible">False</property>
 ...
```